# Does repeated NAND flash erasing cause more wear?

Tags: nand

That is repeatedly erasing pages without programming them. Or does it have to be a erase/program cycle to count?

Comment: Can not find a ready answer with Google..

Comment: Any flash has a limited number of write or erase cycles.

Comment: Errr, what's your point, @EugeneSh.?

Comment: @EugeneSh. Oh, yeah, hence my question

Answer (score 2):

The limit is to the number of erases that the flash cells can undergo. The stress to the cells is the effects of the repeated programming-to-0 and erasure-to-1.

So repeatedly issuing erase commands will be of no detriment to the flash cell life i.e. it won't wear the chip out.

You may also find that the flash chip's internal controller finishes an erase operation more quickly on a blank chip than on one full of zeroes, or half full to them if random data. The controller still has to go through the cell rows and test them but do nothing after testing each row.

Comment: could you provide a source for that? I am trying to make some reliability estimates and "dude told me in stackoverflow" isn't cutting it 

Comment: @FrancoVS, thanks for the upvote and not a single source, no. It's a commonly documented characteristic of FEPROM that you can search for easily enough to find what you need in particular. Examples of the many are the Wikipedia 'Flash memory' article and NXP [AN1837](www.nxp.com/docs/en/application-note/AN1837.pdf)